# Can we have whitespace in the wsdl url for a soap service?

Tags: xml, wsdl

Is this allowed:
http://xxxxxxxxxx:1111/Process Server/services/ProcessServer?wsdl

in the URL of a wsdl?

There is a white space character between Process and Server

Answer (score 0):

WSDL is not special in this regard. An URL to a WSDL is held to the same rules as any URL, as the program that will try to fetch it will most likely use the same implementation of URL-fetching protocol.

A space in the path portion of the URL is perfectly allowed, however, when an HTTP client will query to this URL it will escape this character as %20.

URLs have essentially two ways to be represented: for machine use, where everything that a computer "will find ambiguous" is escaped with %-encoding. Or for user use, which can be pleasantly displayed as visually written or pronounced by voice. There the characters that wouldn't confuse a human on their meaning, need not be encoded. And one space is not exactly confusing. With or without escaping the space with %20 this URL is the same URL and a program trying to fetch it will make the same request. HTTP clients and otherwise URL-fetching programs are in charge to convert URLs from user use to machine use.

So, yes you can have a space in this URL, but if you don't escape it as %20 to make http://xxxxxxxxxx:1111/Process%20Server/services/ProcessServer?wsdl , then you take the risk of running into some issues. It is allowed but discouraged.